# Nested List from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to turn the json data that is in the db variable into a nested list on the html page.  Instead it is giving me a sort of ladder of each child node inserted into the child node before it. I can not figure out why it is not nesting correctly.  What am i missing?

```js
db = JSON.parse(`
                {
                    "title": "Root", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "Child1",
                            "children": [
                                {"title": "Child1a"},
                                {"title": "Child1b"},
                                {"title": "Child1c"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Child2",
                            "children": [
                                {"title": "Child2a"},
                                {"title": "Child2b"},
                                {"title": "Child2c"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            `);

function recurse(u, j) {

  li = document.createElement('li');
  ul = document.createElement('ul');

  li.setAttribute('title', j.title);

  li.appendChild(ul);
  u.appendChild(li);

  (j.children || []).forEach(c => {
    recurse(ul, c);
  });

}

recurse(document.getElementById('tree'), db);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

li::before {
  content: attr(title);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Scratch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id='tree'></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Declare your variables local to the function with `let`.

Comment: Otherwise they're global variables, and when you recurse you overwrite the variables used in the caller.

Comment: *Always* declare your variables.

Comment: wow thank you!  I was not aware that javascript did this.

Comment: @pilchard It's not a typo. But reproducible and exemplary :)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky That's fair, but then should be closed as duplicate for any of the myriad `scope` questions including [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it)

Comment: @pilchard The same fix can solve many problems. And many problems can be based on a common mistake. But the "duplicated question", in my opinion, is more related to describing the problematic behavior when working on a specific task. You can clarify this point by asking a question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to the same variables over and over because you're not re-declaring them in the function scope.

```js
db = JSON.parse(`
                {
                    "title": "Root", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "Child1",
                            "children": [
                                {"title": "Child1a"},
                                {"title": "Child1b"},
                                {"title": "Child1c"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Child2",
                            "children": [
                                {"title": "Child2a"},
                                {"title": "Child2b"},
                                {"title": "Child2c"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            `);

function recurse(u, j) {

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');

  li.setAttribute('title', j.title);

  li.appendChild(ul);
  u.appendChild(li);

  (j.children || []).forEach(c => {
    recurse(ul, c);
  });

}

recurse(document.getElementById('tree'), db);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

li::before {
  content: attr(title);
}

li:hover {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Scratch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id='tree'></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you don't need `let` for this. The good old `var` is just sufficient most of the times.

Comment: @Redu thank you.  yea i tried both and they worked currently googling the difference between the two.

Comment: I typically only use let when declaring a variable in a loop or a block scope and i know i won't need it after the loop or block.